# Smoothness between (Dup)Mirror and Orginal?

Tags: modeling

Hi I am modeling a truck, I modeled its half part and dup + mirrored it for other half. I have a problem and both parts haven't smoothness between them ?

How can I make them smooth ??

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the screenshot representing the grid of your model?

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32977/how-come-my-mirror-modifier-messes-up-when-i-apply-subdivision and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33996/multiresolution-subdivide-modifier-on-a-mirrored-surface-causes-a-visible-seam/34010#34010

Comment: Can we see the order of modifiers on the truck?

Comment: If you are using a mirror modifier, is *Clipping* enabled?